# Excel - Multiply rows that contain a true checkbox by a fixed value

Tags: excel, checkbox

I'm trying to multiply any rows that have a checked checkbox with a flat day rate value and output the result to a total cell.

I've tried the following SUM on the total column without much luck:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$37=TRUE)*($D$3))
```

In pseudo it would be something like:

> Find within these cells (B6-B37) the number of rows that have a true
>   checkbox and multiply that value by the day rate value in D3 and
>   output the result in I11.

So for illustrative purposes, the example below would have a total of 10 because 4 checkboxes are checked and 4 x 2.50 = 10.

[image]

I'm sure it's something simple but I rarely use excel.

Many thanks for your time.

Chris

Comment: what kind of checkboxes have you used? and what you are trying to do is possible if the checkboxes are linked to the cells. but how are they linked to the cells?

Comment: I added them using the developer tab > insert > checkbox. Then clicked in the cell. I then duplicated the cell using the technique outlined here: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/901-excel-insert-multiple-checkboxes.html
I'm open to other ways of doing this as well, this was just what i thought would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=COUNTIF($B$6:$B$37,TRUE)*$D$3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can't get that to work though, does that mean I haven't added the checkboxes correctly? It doesn't error it just returns 0.

Comment: Check the values behind your checkboxes (i.e. copy and paste them elsewhere as values). They should show TRUE and FALSE.